# Where do I start when creating an office add-in for the calendar?

Tags: outlook, office365, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm looking into making an add-in for Outlook, that's used when scheduling an event in the calendar. However, nowhere in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/?view=outlook-js-1.9) I can find information about an add-in in the calendar, only in the mailbox.

Also nowhere else on the internet I can find proper explaination about how to do this. The only issues I can find are usually over 5 years old and written in C#, while the rest of the add-ins are written in JS.

Does anyone know where this information can be found? It would help a lot!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no separate add-ins for the calendar. You can develop a COM add-in (VSTO, for example, written in C# or VB.NET) or web based add-in. The latter is described in depth in the [Outlook add-ins documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/). With Outlook add-ins, you can use familiar web technologies such as HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to build a solution that can run in Outlook across multiple platforms, including on the web, Windows, Mac, and iOS.

Most probably you will find the [Create Outlook add-ins for compose forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/compose-scenario) page helpful.

Comment: Thanks mate, this is exactly what I needed! I just couldn't see the forest through the trees anymore